Helm: How to programmatically pass down a generated CA to all subcharts?
My goal is as follows:

Generate a CA certificate and private key once using Helm's genCA function in a named template.
Use said CA to generate signed certificates for all microservices created by the subcharts.

Below is my unsuccessful attempt to implement this:

In main/templates/_helpers.tpl:
{{/* Generate a common CA certificate for all microservices */}}
{{- define "main.gen-ca-cert" -}}
{{- if not (and .Values.global.CAKey .Values.global.CACertificate) }}
  {{- $ca := genCA "myapp-ca" 365 -}}
  {{- $_ := set .Values.global "CACertificate" ($ca.Cert | b64enc) -}}
  {{- $_ := set .Values.global "CAKey" ($ca.Key | b64enc) -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}


The condition is supposed to ensure that the CA will be generated only once even if main.gen-ca-cert is referenced multiple times. After the CA is generated, the encoded key and certificate are stored as global values for subsequent invocations.
For visibility, I've created the following Secret template under main/templates:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  name: ca-cert
  labels:
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
data:
  tls.crt: {{ .Values.global.CACertificate }}
  tls.key: {{ .Values.global.CAKey }}




In subchart/templates/_helpers.tpl, I use include to invoke main.gen-ca-cert and ensure the global variables are set before using them to generate a signed certificate:
{{/* Generate certificates for the subchart's microservice */}}
{{- define "subchart.gen-certs" -}}
{{- $namespace := .Release.Namespace -}}
{{ include "main.gen-ca-cert" . }}
{{- $ca := buildCustomCert .Values.global.CACertificate .Values.global.CAKey -}}
{{- $serviceName := "myservice" -}}
{{- $serviceFQDN := printf "%s.%s.svc.cluster.local" $serviceName $namespace -}}
{{- $altNames := list $serviceName $serviceFQDN -}}
{{- $cert := genSignedCert $serviceName nil $altNames 365 $ca -}}
tls.crt: {{ $cert.Cert | b64enc }}
tls.key: {{ $cert.Key | b64enc }}
ca.crt: {{ $ca.Cert | b64enc }}
{{- end -}}

Then, I use subchart.gen-certs to populate a Secret under subchart/templates:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  ...
data:
{{ include "subchart.gen-certs" . | indent 2 }}



Using this approach, helm install finishes successfully but I'm getting a unique CA certificate for the subchart's Secret resources, which implies genCA was executed more than once despite my efforts to prevent it. My guess is that it's either a context issue with how I set the global variables, or maybe you just can't manipulate global variables in runtime and have them propagated to all subcharts the way I intended.
Notably, it does work when creating multiple secrets under the main chart, but the subcharts always end up with their own CA certificate.
Is there a way to get this working?

You can't reliably use genCA or other functions that generate random data.  Every time you invoke Helm (including helm upgrade on an existing chart), you'll get a new CA certificate; the old value is never persisted anywhere.  I'd generate the TLS setup externally and inject it, at which point you can use things like .Values.global to pass it around.

Do you control the sub-charts or are they third-party charts?
